# Converting NSString to Date

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsstring, nsdate

I have two strings: date1 = 3-3-2011;

and i want to convert in to 3-March-2011 and display it in label.

```
NSString *myString = 3-3-2011;

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"d-MM-YYYY"];
NSDate *yourDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:myString];



//now format this date to whatever you need…
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"d-MMM-YYYY"];
NSString *resultString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:yourDate];
[dateFormatter release];
```

but yourdate = 2010-12-25 18:30:00 +0000

resultstring = 26-Dec-2010

i want 3-March-2010

please help!
Thank you.

Answer (score 13):

You can use `NSDateFormatter`.

1. Convert your current string to `NSDate` object, so that you can
   convert it into any format you want.

   ```
   NSString *myString          =   @"3-3-2011";
   NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter  =   [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
   [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"d-M-yyy"];
   NSDate *yourDate                =   [dateFormatter dateFromString:myString];
   ```
2. Now you can convert this `NSDate` to any format you want.

   ```
   [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"d-MMMM-yyyy"];
   NSString *resultString          =   [dateFormatter stringFromDate:yourDate];
   [dateFormatter release];
   ```

Apple's documentation on `NSDateFormatter` is [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html).

Comment: NSString *myString = 3-3-2011;

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"d-MM-YYYY"];
NSDate *yourDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:myString];



//now format this date to whatever you need…
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"d-MMM-YYYY"];
NSString *resultString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:yourDate];
[dateFormatter release];

but yourdate = 2010-12-25 18:30:00 +0000

resultstring = 26-Dec-2010

i want 3-March-2010

Comment: @Sam use `@"d-M-yyyy"`. I have no idea how that answer got 2 upvotes.

Comment: @fluchtpunkt is correct on both counts.  The lowercase y is important.  See http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/#Date_Format_Patterns.

Comment: The format string needs to be `@"d-M-yyyy"` in both cases. @"d-M-LLL" and @"d-MMMM-LLLL" are incorrect.

Comment: You should set the Style, not the format, if you want to present the dates appropriately. So set the format for the input(from files etc, not user), but use style when displaying.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [NSDateFormatter](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html). In particular, take a look at the `dateFromString:` and `stringFromDate:` methods. You'll need to convert your original string to an NSDate, then convert that NSDate to another string.

One tip for using NSDateFormatter: be sure always to set a locale. If you don't manually set a locale, it has a bug regarding 12/24 hour clock settings. The example code on the page I linked to shows how to set a locale.

Answer (score 2):

Use d-M-Y (or M-d-Y, depending on which is the month):

```
NSString *myString = 3-3-2011;
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"d-M-Y"];
NSDate *yourDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:myString];
```

And see the [Unicode standard](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns) referred to in the Apple docs.