# How to change the date type to "Jan 21, 2013 5:30 AM" using NSDateFormatter in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, nsdateformatter

I wish to change the date format from "**2013-01-21 11:55:00**" to "**Jan 21, 2013 5:30 AM**".

I tried the below code. But it gives a constant date.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
[dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];

NSDate *myDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:162000];
NSLog(@"%@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:myDate]);
```

**The above code gives constant output : Jan 3, 2001 2:30:00 AM**

But in my case, date is dynamic.

Comment: If you want the output to be dynamic; Your inputs cannot be static. You are passing `162000`, and that's why you are getting constant output (with time changed, I guess).

Comment: http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    NSString *firstDate = @"2013-01-21 11:55:00";
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd  HH':'mm':'ss"];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:firstDate];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMM d, yyyy h:mm a"];

    NSLog(@"Expected Result___ %@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:date]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMM d, yyyy h:mm a"];

NSDate *myDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:162000];
NSLog(@"%@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:myDate];
```

Try `[NSDate date]` instead `[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:162000]`.

Comment: I get a constant "Jan 3, 2001 2:30 AM". But I need the conversion to be dynamic.

Comment: Yes. I have got today's date in the required format now when I used [NSDate date]. Is there anyway I can pass the date dynamically?

Comment: You can get your date from string.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5604657/converting-nsstring-to-date

Answer (score 0):

well you get constant output since you give constant input as 162000 !!!

First get the date from the string using its format then use the new format to get string from the  obtained date

use this to output format as

```
@"MMM d, yyyy h:mm a"

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMM d, yyyy h:mm a"];
NSLog(@"%@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]);
```